# Monitor my internet browsing behaviour

Tags: internet, monitoring, browsing

I need a simple tool (preferably open source) to monitor my Internet browsing behaviour at home. Ideally, this tool should log the website accessed, and the amount of time spent on the site. Reporting features would be ideal.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I use RescueTime as an addon to Firefox : https://www.rescuetime.com/
The browsing is recorded and sent to the website where nice charts are displayed.
(Note: I've made some modifications to the addon to make it work on linux. I don't know why RescueTime didn't test it)

You can also make categories for websites (productive, neutral or distracting) and compare your productivity with other users of the addon.

If the purpose is to reduce your distractions, you can also limit the time you spent on websites with Leechblock (another firefox addon) : [as a new user, I can't post more than one links, so search for "leechblock firefox addon"]

Comment: There's also a Google Chrome version available at http://www.rescuetime.com/chrome

Answer (score 0):

I have used [EyeSpy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eyespy/) for monitoring bit torrent traffic. It provides alot of details about open connections to your PC and should provide the info your looking for.